# direct sum equals direct product iff the index set is finite

Tags: functional-analysis

$I\neq \emptyset$, $X_i$ Banach space. We define $$  \prod_{i\in I} X_i=\{(x_i)_{i\in I}: x_i\in X_i,\;\|(x_i)\|=\sup_{i\in I}\|x_i\|<\infty\}$$and $$  \bigoplus_{i\in I} X_i=\{(x_i)_{i\in I}: x_i\in X_i, (i\mapsto \|a_i\|)\in C_0(I)\},$$ with the discrete topology on $I$.

Why is $\prod_{i\in I} X_i=\bigoplus_{i\in I} X_i \iff I$ is finite?

Let $I$ be finite: $\bigoplus_{i\in I} X_i\subseteq \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ is always true. If $(x_i)\in \prod_{i\in I} X_i$, i.e. $\|(x_i)\|=\sup_{i\in I}\|x_i\|<\infty$, and is $\epsilon >0$ there must exist a finite subset $F\subseteq I$ such that $\|x_i\|<\epsilon $ for all $i\in I\setminus F$. Can I choose $F=I$?

Now let $\prod_{i\in I} X_i=\bigoplus_{i\in I} X_i$, how to prove that $I$ is finite?

Comment: You'll need an additional hypothesis. $\;$

Comment: which hypothesis do you mean?

Comment: non-triviality of your spaces $\;$

Comment: (In fact, you'll also need at least some form of [Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).) $\;$

Comment: oh hm.. then I have no idea how to prove it. Do you know a reference for a proof or do you know the proof ? (I only ask because it is no homework but I need to know that for other stuff)